# Correct way to call angular CSS path

Tags: angular, angular5

I´m new in Angular 5 and I want to get styles installed into `node_modules` folder who is outside `src` folder, so in  `.angular-cli.json` I do something like this:

```
 "styles": [
        "..node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "..node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

But I get:

> ERROR in multi
>   ./src/..node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
>   ./src/..node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
>   ./src/styles.css Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\Tag\Project\Project.WebUI\src..node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css'
>   in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\Tag\Project\Project.WebUI'

It is something confusing like complier don´t detect `..` and it don´t go to proyect route that´s why it return `src..node_modules\`

Can someone says what is the correct way to route that specific folder? Regards

Photo of structure:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, and you're correct that the file paths are relative to the `app` folder, but you still need a slash preceding the folder name.

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

:)

EDIT: Just a note: changing the `angular-cli.json` will require you to kill and re-run `ng serve` before those changes will be recognized.